# how config crl list by NettyServerBuilder?

Tags: ssl, netty, grpc-java

io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder support config crl list and how config crl list by NettyServerBuilder.

version grpc-netty: 1.44.1

I can not find document which introduce how config crl list.

I just find how to config keyManager and trustCert by SslContextBuilder.keyManager and SslContextBuilder.trustManager

Comment: I responded at https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10335 to say "you have to configure the TrustManager yourself."

Answer (score 0):

```
sslHandler.handshakeFuture().addListener(new MyGenericFutureListener(sslHandler,crlPath));
```

MyGenericFutureListener ：

```
public class MyGenericFutureListener implements GenericFutureListener<DefaultPromise<Channel>> {
SslHandler sslHandler;
String crlPath;

public MyGenericFutureListener(SslHandler sslHandler, String crlPath) {
    this.sslHandler = sslHandler;
    this.crlPath = crlPath;
}

@Override
public void operationComplete(DefaultPromise<Channel> channelFuture) throws Exception {
    if (channelFuture.isSuccess()) {
        SSLSession sslSession = sslHandler.engine().getSession();
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) sslSession.getPeerCertificates()[0];
        if (isCertificateRevoked(cert)) {
            log.error("Certificate revoked");
            //channelFuture.get().close();
        }
    }
}



@SneakyThrows
private boolean isCertificateRevoked(X509Certificate cert) {
    X509CRL crl = (X509CRL) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCRL(new FileInputStream(crlPath));
    return crl.isRevoked(cert);
}
```